# Error with TSNE algorithm with malahanois distance in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following code to plot my data using TSNE feature reduction algorithm in matlab

```
data=dlmread('features.txt');

meas=data(:,2:end);
species=data(:,1);

rng('default'); % for reproducibility
Y = tsne(meas,'Algorithm','exact','Distance','mahalanobis');
gscatter(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),species);
title('Mahalanobis');
```

However, by running it I have the following problem:

> The covariance matrix for the Mahalanobis metric must be symmetric and
>   positive definite.
>
> Error in tsne (line 323)
>           tempDistMat = pdist(X,distance);
>
> Error in plotafeatures (line 7) Y =
>   tsne(meas,'Algorithm','exact','Distance','mahalanobis');

With other distances the plot occurs correctly, what is possibly happening with my code or data?

My data can be found [HERE](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ra023169/features.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed specifically with the `Mahalanobis` distance.

According to the `tsne`[documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne.html), paragraph about [distances](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne.html#namevaluepairarguments):

> 'mahalanobis' — Mahalanobis distance, computed using the **positive definite covariance matrix nancov(X)**.

It seems that your matrix `meas` doesn't fulfil this requirement. You can confirm if with the `chol` function. As the [documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html) says:

> [R,p] = chol(A) for positive definite A (...) p is zero. **If A is not positive definite, then p is a positive integer**.

I tried with your data:

```
data=dlmread('features.txt');
meas=data(:,2:end);
[~, p] = chol(nancov(meas))
```

It returned p = 389, so `nancov(meas)` is not positive definite.

It works with other distances because they don't have that kind of requirement.

Comment: Thanks! so this distance cannot be computed with any kind of data, right?